# Open the mobile device share dialog via web app

Tags: javascript, html

Problem:
We would like to open the mobile devices own share dialog when the user clicks on a button in our website, so that they have their local apps available.

Now: Is it even possible to get to the devices share dialog through the web browser on a phone?

We use only HTML5, CSS3 and Javascript for the websites, so no Android SDK or iPhone equivalent.

Comment: are you facing some problem in code ??

Comment: No, I think no. To get the possible applications where to share the content, you need access to the device, and you can't throught the web browser. The nearest alternative is using cordova or something like that.

Comment: @Abhishek Ghosh No, we are not facing troubles. We wanted to know if it is even possible because we haven't found an answer on stackoverflow or somewhere else yet.

Comment: @JoséAntonioPostigo Thank you for your fast reply. Then we will have to look into some other possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently as José said it is not possible to access the devices share dialog directly through a web browser. Further investigations into other possibilities will be done on our side.